# Why does Text expand when changing contentMode of an Image inside a ZStack?

Tags: ios, swift, image, swiftui, contentmode

I have a SwiftUI View that looks like this:

```swift
@State var showFullScreen: Bool = false

ZStack {
    Image(uiImage: image)
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: showFullscreen ? .fill : .fit)
        .padding(showFullscreen ? 0 : 16)
            
    VStack {
        Spacer()
                
        Label("{switchViewsMessage}".localized(), systemImage: "hand.point.up.left.fill")
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .center)
            .padding()
            .background(bgColor)
            .applyShape(.rounded)
    }
    .padding()
}
.onTapGesture { withAnimation { showFullscreen.toggle() } }
.navigationBarTitle("{photo}".localized())
```

When the `State` is set to `showFullScreen = false`, everything looks like expected. However, when setting `showFullScreen` to `true`, the Image changes to `.fill` to take the whole Screen but also the Text with the Gray Background becomes wider than the Screen.

Why does the Text also expand in Width when changing the State?

Comment: Due to `.frame(maxWidth: .infinity`... it allows to fill all available space which appeared in container because of expanded image.

Comment: @Asperi Thanks. Is there any way I can still allow the Image to expand while the Text can only fill the available Screen Space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way I can still allow the Image to expand while the Text can only fill the available Screen Space?

Use instead the following schema - separate image and text by placing each in own space: image in background, text in overlay, like

```
Color.clear           // << fills screen space (taking into account safe area
  .background(

     ... your image here

  )
  .overlay(

    VStack {
       ... your text here
    }

  )
  .onTapGesture { withAnimation { showFullScreen.toggle() } }
```